# Hide IOS keyboard with multiple textFields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 2 textFields side by side, countryCodeTextField and cellphoneTextField

On countryCodeTextField. I have an action selectCountry that happens on `Edit Did Begin` on the countryCodeTextField

```
- (IBAction)selectCountry:(id)sender {
    countryCodeTextField.delegate = self;
    [countryCodeTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

- Note that self implements the `<UITextFieldDelegate>`.

Problem is when user click's cellphone the keyboard is displayed if he clicks on countryCodeTextField the keyboard is never dismissed.

If the person clicks the countryCode first then the keyboard never appears(which is what I want).

Why isn't the keyboard hidden when the user clicks cellphoneTextField first and then countryCodeTextField?

Comment: Did you apply the code to your cellphoneTextField?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question: what's the desired behaviour? Why do you want to dismiss the keyboard as soon as the user taps on the country code text field?

Comment: That is a good point, wouldn't you want the keyboard to show?

Comment: @Morgan Harris: I just open a subview with list of countries the user can select instead of typing them, so I don't need a keyboard.

Comment: If you don't need a keyboard, do you need it to be a UITextField?  Make it a UILabel.

Comment: @ChrisH labels look different. It would look "ugly". I want it to look like a textField.

Comment: Ok, fair enough - I've put a simple way around this in an answer so I can format.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the user to be able to edit a particular UITextField, set it to not be enabled.

```
 UITextField *textField = ... // Allocated somehow
 textfield.enabled = NO
```

Or just check the enabled checkbox in Interface Builder.  Then the textfield will still be there and you'll be able to update it by configuring the text.  But as sort of mentioned in comments, users expect UITextFields to be editable.

Also, why are you setting the delegate in the IBAction callback?  I would think you'd be better off doing this in Interface Builder or when you create the UITextField in code.

EDIT:

Ok - so you want users to be able to select the box, but then bring up a custom subview(s) from which they select something which will fill the box.

So set the UITextField delegate when you create it (as mentioned above) and implement the following from the UITextFieldDelegate protocol:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     return NO;
}
```

to return NO.  Note that if you are using the same delegate for both of your UITextFields, you will need to make this method return YES for the other field.  For example, something like:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   if (textField == countryTextField)  
       return NO;
   return YES;
}
```

Hopefully this should stop the keyboard being displayed - and now you have to work out how to fire your own subviews, which I'd suggest doing via an IBAction (touch up or something perhaps).  You'll have to test various things out here, but remember you're kinda corrupting the point of UITextField and maybe it'll work and maybe it won't, and maybe it'll break in the next iOS upgrade.

Comment: This doesn't work, that will actually make the textField not respond to any events. I still want it to be editable, just not through the keyboard.

Comment: Ahh ok, you're now dangerously into changing the standard behaviour of UI tools that you're just going to mess with users.

Comment: Tried your new idea. Good idea, but no unfortunately it did not work. The keyboard is still up from selecting the cellphoneField, and it didn't hide it.

Comment: Ok, you need to treat that as a separate issue and dismiss the keyboard when it completes editing (or when the user selects something else) using the resignFirstResponder.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first, I think you shouldn't be using a UITextField. I think you should be using a UIButton and have the current value showing as the button's title. However, if you have your heart set on it, I would use our good friend `inputView`, a property on `UITextField`, and set that to your custom input view (which I assume is a UIPickerView or similar.)

This has the added bonus of not breaking your app horribly for blind and visually impaired users, something you should probably be aware of before you go messing about with standard behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In your method :

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing: (UITextField *)textField
```

call this :
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];

and  apply checks for the two fields i.e., when textField is the countryCodeTextField write :

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

and call your method :

```
[self selectCountry];
```

In this method display the list of country codes.

So Your code will be :

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}
 - (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing: (UITextField *)textField{

    [textField becomeFirstResponder];

    if (textField == countryCodeTextField){

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self selectCountry];
    }
}

-(IBAction)selectCountry{
    //display the list no need to do anything with the textfield.Only set text of TextField as the selected countrycode.
}
```